# Spoon takes insanely long time to start

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am running Spoon - Pentaho EE V 6.1 on my laptop (8 GB RAM) and allocated 4 G to Spoon. Still it takes 3 minutes and 30 seconds to start. I dont have any plugins and my plugins directory is empty. I have also tried this by closing all applications and processes but with no luck. Am I missing anything obvious?

```
Sep 22, 2017 10:15:13 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener addExtensions
INFO: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-javascript (208) [org.apache.cxf.javascript.JavascriptServerListener]
Sep 22, 2017 10:15:13 AM org.pentaho.caching.impl.PentahoCacheManagerFactory$Reg
istrationHandler$1 onSuccess
INFO: New Caching Service registered
2017/09/22 10:15:27 - General - Logging plugin type found with ID: CheckpointLog    Table
2017/09/22 10:18:00,201 ERROR [KarafLifecycleListener] Error in Blueprint Watcher org.pentaho.osgi.api.IKarafBlueprintWatcher$BlueprintWatcherException: Unknown error in KarafBlueprintWatcher at org.pentaho.osgi.impl.KarafBlueprintWatcherImpl.waitForBlueprint(KarafBlueprintWatcherImpl.java:103) at org.pentaho.di.osgi.KarafLifecycleListener$2.run(KarafLifecycleListen    er.java:161) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.pentaho.osgi.api.IKarafBlueprintWatcher$BlueprintWatcherException : Timed out waiting for blueprints to load: pdi-dataservice-server-plugin,pentaho-big-data-impl-shim-initializer,pentaho-big-data-impl-shim-hdfs,pentaho-big-data-impl-shim-hbase,pentaho-big-data-impl-shim-mapreduce,pentaho-big-data-impl-shim-pig,pentaho-big-data-impl-shim-oozie,pentaho-big-data-impl-shim-sqoop,pentaho-big-data-impl-vfs-hdfs,pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-common-named-cluster-bridge,pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-guiTestActionHandlers,pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-hdfs,pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-hbase,pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-mapreduce,pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-pig,pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-oozie,pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-sqoop,pentaho-hadoop-shims-mapr-osgi-jaas,pentaho-big-data-impl-clusterTests,pentaho-big-data-impl-shim-shimTests,pentaho-yarn-api,pentaho-yarn-impl-shim,pentaho-yarn-kettle-plugin,pentaho-metaverse-core,pentaho-metaverse-web,pentaho-requirejs-osgi-manager,pentaho-angular-bundle,common-ui-6.1.0.1,pentaho-marketplace-di at org.pentaho.osgi.impl.KarafBlueprintWatcherImpl.waitForBlueprint(KarafBlueprintWatcherImpl.java:88)
        ... 2 more
2017/09/22 10:18:42 - General - Starting agile-bi
2017/09/22 10:18:43 - class org.pentaho.agilebi.platform.JettyServer - WebServer.Log.CreateListener localhost:10001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer. Its a known issue and fixed under Version 7

There seems to be a timing issue in the Karaf Blueprint Watcher where sometimes it will ask a bundle for its blueprint file before the bundle is in RESOLVED state. This triggers a (usually) parallel resolve that causes the bundle to be destroyed immediately after creation.

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-15488

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-14698

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-15574

Comment: "There seems" is to remain polite. Remove all the plugins (the content of the plugin folder) and restart spoon. Don't do that without a backup, just in case some of your transformation relies on a plugin. In which case, copy only that one in the plugin folder.

Comment: None of my transformations are relying on any plugin. Hence emptied the plugin folder. Apparently we can fix this through some settings (as referred in one of the tickets), but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @AdityaWirayudha Yes you need to upgrade but no quick win on this version